# Inbox icon flashes when I read message on other page, feature or bug

Tags: bug, global-inbox

When I read message in a page and switch to inactive page, I got inbox flashing.
It keeps flashing all the time even I click on inbox icon until I reload page.

It happens in different browser window not in the tabs of a same browser window.

See this

[image]

I am on Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak so your gif isn't just on repeat?? It actually flashes *multiple times*?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It is flashing all the time, I recorded gif for 3 seconds

Comment: OK... that looks like a bug :/

Comment: repro possible on SO not on Meta though

Comment: You might have been "trolled" by someone, .e.g. by writing a comment then instantly deleting it, repeating it over and over.

Comment: try in a separate browser window, not in the tabs of same window

Comment: hmm... OK, too weird too be explained easily then.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak any JS/sockets errors in console?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There was no as far as I realize. No repro at the moment

Comment: OK, maybe some temp glitch on your side.